# Bound of an Integrable function (Analysis)

Tags: integration, analysis, functions, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

For non-negative Riemann integrable function f in [a,b], and dissection $\mathcal D= {x_0,x_1,...,x_n } $, if $p(f,\mathcal D) $ is defined as $$p(f,\mathcal D)=\prod_{k=1}^n [1+(x_k-x_{k-1}) \inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)]$$
How do you proof that $p(f,\mathcal D) < e^{\int_{a}^b f(x)dx} $?

Comment: A hint on the question was to use e^x>x+1 but I couldn’t get to the stage that it is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (using $\exp(x) = e^x$ for greater clarity):
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n[1 + (x_k-x_{k-1})\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)]\le
\prod_{k=1}^n\exp\left((x_k-x_{k-1})\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)\right) =
$$
$$ 
= \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{(x_k-x_{k-1})\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)}\right)
$$
(Why the $\le$ and the $=$?)

Comment: not sure by Why the ≤ and the = question but i have now got it! thanks

Comment: @2569cfa, the inequality from the original hint and $e^x e^y = e^{x + y}$.